# How can I specify that a trait function takes an argument implementing the trait?

Tags: rust, abstract-data-type

I created an abstract data type for vectors in metric space but the compiler complains because it doesn't recognize that the implementation as an argument is of this type.

```
trait MetricPoint {
    fn square_distance(&self, other: &MetricPoint) -> f64;
}

struct RNPoint {
    coordinates: Vec<f64>,
}

impl RNPoint {
    fn new(coordinates: &[f64]) -> RNPoint {
        RNPoint {
            coordinates: coordinates.to_vec(),
        }
    }
}

impl MetricPoint for RNPoint {
    fn square_distance(self: &RNPoint, other: &RNPoint) -> f64 {
        let min_len = self.coordinates.len().min(other.coordinates.len());
        let mut sum = 0.0;
        for i in 0..min_len {
            let diff = self.coordinates[i] - other.coordinates[i];
            sum += diff * diff;
        }
        sum
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn square_distance() {
        let p1 = RNPoint::new(&[0.0, 0.0]);
        let p2 = RNPoint::new(&[1.0, 0.0]);
        let d = p1.square_distance(&p2);
        assert_eq!(d, 1.0)
    }
}
```

The compiler:

```
error[E0053]: method `square_distance` has an incompatible type for trait
  --> points/src/lib.rs:19:44
   |
2  |     fn square_distance(&self, other: &MetricPoint) -> f64;
   |                                      ------------ type in trait
...
19 |     fn square_distance(self:&RNPoint,other:&RNPoint)->f64 {
   |                                            ^^^^^^^^ expected trait MetricPoint, found struct `RNPoint`
   |
   = note: expected type `fn(&RNPoint, &dyn MetricPoint) -> f64`
              found type `fn(&RNPoint, &RNPoint) -> f64`
```

Why it doesn't recognize that an `RNPoint` is an `MetricPoint`?

Comment: I you want the type of the implementor, use `Self`

Comment: BTW, you can use this answer to compute the sum: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56930343/multiplying-elements-from-two-different-arrays : https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b19103b2509e041c72585561c9d3b0a1

Comment: There is no such things as an *"abstract class"* in Rust. Please stick to the correct terminology.

Comment: You might change your title to "how to tell a trait function to take an argument implementing this trait" or something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not far from something that compiles and pass your test. Just change:

```rust
fn square_distance(&self, other: &MetricPoint) -> f64;
```

to

```rust
fn square_distance(&self, other: &Self) -> f64;
```

and optionnally

```rust
fn square_distance(self: &RNPoint, other: &RNPoint) -> f64
```

to

```rust
fn square_distance(self: &RNPoint, other: &Self) -> f64
```

By writing `Self`, you are specifying the type of the current structure. It's more generic and readable.

Comment: Please explain why the changes are needed and where one can find some information about `Self` (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/32304595)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. As some said but Hugo more clearly the solution is the self. Here is the final code:

```
trait Metric {
    fn distance(&self, other: &Self) -> f64;
}

struct RNPoint {
    coordinates: Vec<f64>,
}

impl RNPoint {
    fn new(coordinates: &[f64]) -> RNPoint {
        RNPoint {
            coordinates: coordinates.to_vec(),
        }
    }
}

impl Metric for RNPoint {

    fn distance(&self, other: &Self) -> f64 {
        let sum:f64=self.coordinates.iter()
            .zip(other.coordinates.iter())
            .map(|(&c1, &c2)| {
                let diff = c1 - c2;
                diff * diff
            })
            .sum();
         sum.sqrt()
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_distance() {
        let p1 = RNPoint::new(&[0.0, 0.0]);
        let p2 = RNPoint::new(&[1.0, 0.0]);
        let d = p1.distance(&p2);
        assert_eq!(d, 1.0)
    }
}
```

About the abstract class I wrote Abstract Data Type but stack overflow changed it and I didn't notice. Sorry about